# tmux: Chaining `send-key Enter` and `refresh -S` in key bind

Tags: tmux

I am trying to configure tmux such that it always refreshes the client (or the clients status bar) when the "enter"-key is pressed. I currently using

```
bind -n enter send-key Enter; refresh -S
```

but the behavior is strange. It does send the `Enter` every time and therefore I can use the key as normal, but the `refresh -S` is not always executed. I test the configuration with the status-bar setting

```
set -g status-left "#{pane_current_path}"
```

s. t. it should then immediately update when entering `cd` commands. But this does not happen. When entering a `cd` to somewhere the status bar gets only updated in the standard cycle, i. e. sometimes delayed. If I enter another command (or a blank line) shortly after the `cd` the status bar indeed gets updated immediately.

The same happens with `send-key KPEnter` instead of just `Enter`.

Anybody with a clue what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a race condition.

Expanding `#{pane_current_path}` requires the tmux server to learn the current working directory of the process being the "main one" in the pane. It doesn't matter how the tmux server learns or already knows which process this is, the point is the process is not a part of tmux, it's a separate process.

Often, like in your case, the "main process" in a pane is an interactive shell.

Tmux server may learn the current working directory of this shell by checking `/proc/<PID>/cwd`, where `<PID>` denotes the PID of the shell; or by some equivalent method.

When you type `cd whatever`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and your `send-key Enter; refresh -S` works, `send-key Enter` makes the shell start interpreting `cd whatever`. The important thing is `send-key` just sends the key, it does not wait for any effect of this action; and the shell just *starts* interpreting `cd whatever`, interpreting and executing is going to take some time; but *without any delay* tmux proceeds to `refresh -S` which makes the tmux server start refreshing the client's status line, which involves evaluating `#{pane_current_path}`. The shell (triggered by `send-key`) and the tmux server (triggered by `refresh`) do their tasks *in parallel* and there is no guarantee the shell manages to actually change its current working directory before `#{pane_current_path}` gets evaluated.

If the format string is evaluated first then you will see the old working directory in the status line.

Another command or a blank line shortly after the `cd` makes `#{pane_current_path}` return the new current working directory because <kbd>Enter</kbd> here is late enough, the shell has managed to change its working directory.

A good way to cause `cd` in your interactive shell to refresh the status line  without a race is to make `cd` itself trigger `refresh -S` after it actually changes the working directory:

```sh
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
   cd () {
      command cd "$@"
      (
         status="$?"
         tmux refresh -S
         return "$status"
      )
   }
fi
```

If the shell is inside tmux then the above snippet will create a shell function that overloads the `cd` builtin.

Notes:

1. The shell code itself is portable. The only non-portable part is the invocation of `tmux`.
2. Existence of an alias for `cd` will make the snippet fail or misbehave. In Bash you can solve this problem by replacing `cd ()` with non-portable `function cd`.
3. The function retains the exit status of the actual `cd`.
4. Invoking `tmux` asynchronously (`tmux refresh -S &`) will make the shell not wait for it, while not breaking the solution. I'm pointing this out because in your original attempt with `bind` the shell also does not wait, so *maybe* this is what you prefer. But if the asynchronous `tmux` fails (very unlikely though) and prints an error message then the message may appear after the next shell prompt, which will be confusing. For this reason IMO it's *more elegant* to invoke `tmux` synchronously. It's true that invoking `tmux` asynchronously may save few milliseconds; most likely in an interactive shell you won't notice the difference though.

Comment: Tank you for your very thorough reply, this perfectly answers my question. The key takeaway for me is, that tmux executes separate commands bound to one keystroke in parallel.

Comment: @ginger314 No, tmux itself does not execute them in parallel. `send-key` acts first, `refresh` acts later; but `send-key` just sends the key, it's not `send-key-and-wait-for-output-like-prompt` nor whatever.

Comment: @ginger314 The answer is now more descriptive in this matter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.